# Knockout computed array not updating

Tags: knockout.js

I am facing an issue that the computed observable array is not updated when a new item is added.

```
self.FilteredCityList = ko.computed(function() {
  var filteredCollection = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CityListCollection(), function(r) {
    var matchingItem = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.LocationCollection(), function(r1) {
      return r1.LocationCode() == r.LocationCode();
    });
    if (matchingItem.length > 0) {
     return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  return filteredCollection;
}, this);
```

When I add an item in `self.LocationCollection()` the computed array is not updated.

Comment: It seems your code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/egFSh/ it updates the `FilteredCityList` when adding items to `LocationCollection`. Can you maybe put together a sample jsfiddle which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Thanks dude. Its working now. I have added a item using self.LocationCollection().push(item). Now after seeing yours, i changed to self.LocationCollection.push(item). Can you let me know whats wrong with mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've mentioned in your comment that you've used the following code to add items to your `LocationCollection` which caused your problem:

```
self.LocationCollection().push(item);
```

Where

```
self.LocationCollection = ko.observableArray();
```

To enable knockout's change tracking you need to call `push` on the `observableArray` directly (e.g. without the parenthesis `()`) [as described in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):

```
self.LocationCollection.push(item);
```

But what is the difference?

The `ko.observableArray()` call will return a function. To get the underlying array you need to call this function (e.g `self.LocationCollection()`) which returns the stored array.

At this point when you call `LocationCollection().push(item)` you will call `push` on the underlying array so knockout won't know about it and it doesn't trigger your computed observable.

That's why in knockout they defined their own `push` method on the `observableArray` itself what you need to call with the syntax `LocationCollection.push(item)` and because it's knockout's method it will correctly track the changes.

[Sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/egFSh/)

Comment: +1 - Kudos on the way you helped identify the real problem, which was not directly apparent in his initial description.